# Stopping access to a website using a direct server IP

Tags: apache-2.2

I need help with virtualhost settings in apache2. I do not want users to access my website directly using a server ip like http://55.66.77.88 and want to ensure that it opens only when the particular domain (example.com) is typed in. The direct ip access should result in a redirect the example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Using mod_rewrite this should work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

But this should be moved to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Just create a default VirtualHost which will be defined before any other VirtualHost. If the HTTP/1.1 `Host` header contains a domain which no VirtualHost exists for, no domain at all or if HTTP/1.0 is used, the default VirtualHost will be served to the client.

You can easily put a `RedirectPermanent` directive inside that default VirtualHost.

For details see [In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html) in the Apache httpd documentation.

> If no matching vhost could be found the request is served from the first vhost with a matching port number that is on the list for the IP to which the client connected (as already mentioned before).