# What enables Cloudflare to disable direct IP address access?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

When I visit a website that has Cloudflare, using the website's IP address, I get this message:

```
Error 1003
Direct IP access not allowed


What happened?

You've requested an IP address that is part of the Cloudflare network.
A valid Host header must be supplied to reach the desired website.
```

I am a student.

1. What does allow Cloudflare to block direct IP address access?
2. Is not DNS a layer above the IP address? If yes, being Cloudflare a DNS service, why does Cloudflare have the capacity to block IP addresses?

Comment: @jonathanjo Direct ip address access is blocked because CloudFlare has an HTTP Server Proxy?

Comment: DNS is not a layer. It is a service. This question is likely listed on the Systems Admin stack however I can't easily look that up from the mobile interface.

Comment: I suggest you also go look at cloudflare's services offered page to understand what they are offering in a more complete way.

Comment: If you are talking about layers, IP addresses should "never" be used on the application layer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing special in the cloudflare setup.  This is just a property of HTTP.

When a client opens a URL, there are three important steps:

1. If required, it makes a DNS (or other resolution method) to turn a hostname into an IP address.  If the URL specifies an IP address for the host, use that.
2. It makes a connection to that IP address on a well-known port number, normally 80 (unless it's overridden in the URL)
3. It asks the server for the page, **including the desired hostname**.

A classical example looks like this:

```
GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org
```

Consider a large host with many web sites on it.  For simplicity let's say it has a single IP address.  Hundreds of domain names resolve to this address.  How does the server decide which pages to deliver?  It uses the host detail given by the client in the HTTP request.  If you ask for something it doesn't have or want to give you, it will give you an error response.

In your case, the request contains an IP address for the host specifier.

```
GET /whatever HTTP/1.1
Host: a.b.c.d
```

Very many hosts decide not to give out pages when the host is specified by IP address.  There's nothing special about Cloudflare here, nor is it to do with DNS.  It's about how the server responds to requests for the host specified by IP address, and you can see that this error message specifies that `A valid Host header must be supplied`.

Here's an answer which describes how to configure a server in this way: https://serverfault.com/a/607222

You can easily verify this kind of behaviour by using telnet to connect to a server and issue the HTTP request manually.

PS.  The same general answer applies to an HTTP**S** request, but using [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) in the setup.  It's worth noting that `Host` came in with HTTP 1.1 (1997).  Prior to that, the mechanism described here didn't exist, and a server had no way to reliably tell if the client had asked for a name which legitimately resolved to its IP address, or had asked for the host by IP address directly.  As this was an important development for the explosive growth in web sites, many older clients were updated to send `Host`. [Thanks commenters for picking up on details.]

Comment: So, I can say that this behaviour is because of Cloudflare's HTTP server proxy?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It could be anything at the receiving end.  In cloudflare's case there will be large infrastructure, and it is likely they filter out as early as possible.  Perhaps there's a load balancer, perhaps there's a reverse proxy, perhaps there's a whole server dedicated to "hostname misses".

Comment: Thank you @jonathanjo

Comment: The (PS) is misleading, HTTPS works differently. It uses SNI (Server Name Indication) to set up an encrypted TLS connection. With a different hostname you'd get a different encrypted connection. Yes, there's a HTTP connection inside the encrypted connection, but the encryption means you can't see the hostname in there. That's why SNI is needed.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for picking me up on that, I've edited the answer.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that _originally_ the "Host:" header did not exist (it only became mandatory with HTTP 1.1). So  in the (very) early days of HTTP the server indeed did not know whether users connected by hostname or by IP address. But nowadays the Host: header is mandatory.

Comment: @sleske thanks for mentioning that, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that although the "Host:" header wasn't introduced until HTTP 1.1, many HTTP 1.0 clients were updated to include it, since it was fairly trivial to implement.

Comment: @cjm thanks for comment, updated answer.  Certainly it was a big deal in the ISP I worked in, as we were gaining web hosting clients at a rapid pace and it was burning through our address allocation very wastefully.

Answer (score 1):

The system you are trying to contact has multiple sites listed in its httpd config.

The only way the HTTP server can differentiate the various sites hosted on it are with direct URLs.

Since those sites are hosted on CloudFlare's hardware, they can provide whatever error the wish.  CDN's (Content Delivery Networks) shift the connection to the closest cached copy across their network based on several factors.

If you look at what CloudFlare offers as a service, you will see that part of the setup process you repoint your domains DNS records to their dns servers which then utilize only their CDN systems. As a developer, If you are using a CDN, you still know where your actual hosts are located and can contact them directly, customers no longer have that access.

That also helps isolate your hosts from DDos Attacks. The CDN still contacts your host for content unless your entire infrastructure is hosted within the CDNs network.